# Query Error - Timeout

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, automationstudio

my query had an error "QUERY FAILED - TIMEOUT".

The query is:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
S.JobID, 
S.ListID, 
S.BatchID, 
S.SubscriberID, 
I.ActivityName, 
I.JourneyName, 
I.JourneyId, 
I.VersionId, 
S.EventDate, 
T.Country_ISO_Code_1__c AS Country,
S.SubscriberKey,
'True' AS Sent
FROM Journey_JobId_INFO_Rolling AS I
INNER JOIN _Sent AS S 
ON I.TriggeredSendCustomerKey = S.TriggeredSendCustomerKey
AND S.JobId = I.JobId 
LEFT JOIN Account_Salesforce AS T 
ON T.PersonContactId = S.SubscriberKey
```

The query is in UPDATE.
Someone can help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What's the primary key of the target DE?

Comment: I question the join to _Sent by TriggeredSendCustomerKey.  The relationship from _Sent to a Journey send does not include that field.  See: https://sfmarketingcloudhome.files.wordpress.com/2021/02/dataviews_2021_v2.png

Comment: @AdamSpriggs the primary keys are:
JobID, ListID and Batch id.
About you doubt: "I question the join to _Sent by TriggeredSendCustomerKey. The relationship from _Sent to a Journey send does not include that field",  I must specify that there is a query preceding this one, which extracts data from the 'Journey and Jourbey Activity' data view.

Comment: The query is:
SELECT DISTINCT
J.JourneyName,
J.JourneyId,
J.VersionId,
S.JobId,
A.ActivityName,
S.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID,
S.TriggeredSendCustomerKey
FROM _Journey AS J
INNER JOIN _JourneyActivity AS A
ON J.VersionID = A.VersionID
INNER JOIN _Sent AS S
ON A.JourneyActivityObjectID = S.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
WHERE J.JourneyId = 'b729eda5-1af2-42ac-b9a8-9794e2eebd05'

Comment: The primary key of JobID+ListID+BatchID on the target DE will result in a primary key violation if it didn't timeout.  You're selecting activity by subscriber over time.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs thank Adam. But i dont understand why my primary keys are not ok. Previously the query has worked correctly,but now (10 days) is always in error (timeout)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following for the primary key fields for your target Data Extension:

- jobid
- listID
- batchid
- versionid
- subscriberid
- eventDate

You could simplify your two queries into a single one by not selecting _Sent records twice:

```sql
select top 1 with ties
  s.jobID 
, s.listID 
, s.batchID 
, s.subscriberID 
, j.journeyName 
, j.journeyId 
, j.versionId 
, ja.ActivityName 
, s.eventDate 
, s.subscriberKey
, a.country_ISO_Code_1__c Country
, 1 Sent
from _Sent s
left join Account_Salesforce a on a.PersonContactId = s.subscriberKey
inner join _JourneyActivity ja on a.JourneyActivityObjectID = s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID 
inner join _Journey j on j.versionId = a.versionId
where J.JourneyId = 'b729eda5-1af2-42ac-b9a8-9794e2eebd05'
order by row_number() over (
    partition by 
      s.jobid
    , s.listID
    , s.batchid
    , j.versionid
    , s.subscriberId
    , convert(date, s.eventDate) 
    order by s.eventDate desc
)
```

The `top 1 with ties` and the `order by row_number() over (partition by...` will sort the results by the partitioned fields and choose only the most recent one per day, ensuring that you don't violate the primary key fields I listed above.